# Can we use a photon to use it as a changing field in an electric generator?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, field-theory

In an electric generator we use a changing magnetic field to create electricity. But what if we use a photon's oscillation of EM waves to generate electricity in a metal wire as we do in an electric generator? Also if instead of a photon we use a changing EM field instead of a M wave what would happen? Would it still generate electricity?

Comment: Please read about [the relationship between an electromagnetic wave and photon](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90646/50583) first. What do you mean by "a photon's oscillation of EM waves" when an EM wave only is there when there are *very many photons*?

Comment: How is that different from a photodetector?

Answer (score 3):

Electromagnetic waves can definitely excite currents in conductive materials; objects which use this behavior are called [antennas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_(radio)).